# How to add attachment_ids in odoo message?

Tags: react-native, odoo-10

i'm trying to add attachment in a odoo message programmly using react-native-odoo-promise-based.

first i've create ir.attachment and it show success value 
{success: true, data: 1096}.

then i try to add this id (1096) to attachment_ids in mail.message

```
    const data = {
            message_type: "comment",
            add_sign: false,
            reply_to: "Mitchell Admin <test@test.com>",
            attachment_ids: [1096],
            body: '<p>Coba WhiteCake</p>',
            create_date: "2019-05-20 08:15:47",
            display_name: "PO00013 (44)",
            record_name: "PO00013 (44)",
            author_id: 3,
            add_sign: false,

        }
        odoo.create('mail.message', data)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
                console.log('eror')
            });
    });
```

it show success result too,

```
    {success: true, data: 1178}
```

then i've read mail.messsage id 1178

```
    add_sign: false
    attachment_ids: []
```

but attachment_ids still has an empty array.

i've already try this :

attachment_id: ['1096']

attachment_id: [(0,'1096')]

attachment_id: [(0,1096)],

attachment_id: [(1096)],

attachment_id: 1096,

attachment_id: [1096],

attachment_ids: [1096],

attachment_ids: [(1096)],

attachment_ids: [('1096')],

attachment_ids: [(0,'1096')],

attachment_ids: [(0,1096)],

attachment_ids: [('0','1096')],

attachment_ids: [(0,1096)],

attachment_ids: '[1096]',

but attachment_ids still has an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

**attachment_ids** is a m2m field so you can not directly write like this. You can write like

```
'attachment_ids': [(6, 0, orphan_attachment_ids)],
```

And for this you can also refer base code of mail.message There is an example provided by community.

Comment: it doesnt work for me, attachment_ids still has an empty array.

Comment: can you share a link that provide the example in react-native?

Comment: What is your actual functional usage can you explain something here ?

Comment: i want to add a comment (message that has an attachment)  in purchase order